# Testing custom intent Google Assistant capability in beta close (Close Testing)

Tags: android, google-assistant-sdk, google-assistant

I have developed an app that utilizes a custom intent from Google Assistant to trigger specific functionalities within the app. As part of the development process, I have only been able to publish the app to beta close testing due to its exploratory nature.

One challenge I encountered is related to the usage of different Google Assistant emails. In the current state, the app requires manual configuration in the App Action plugin on Android Studio for each unique Google Assistant email. This manual setup is necessary to ensure that the custom intent seamlessly works with the designated functionalities.

I am exploring options to streamline this process and enable the app to work with different Google Assistant emails without the need for manual configuration in the App Action plugin. Will it work properly after being published to beta testing (close testing) when using a different Google Assistant email without the need to configure it manually in the App Action plugin on Android Studio?

What exactly the release steps in Google Play Console should be completed/uploaded to so we can use our personal email to trigger app action on our app?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.